# Symfony 3 : GroupSequence in validation_groups

Tags: php, symfony

In my entity, I have that field :

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex("/^[a-z0-9-]+$/", groups={"Basic1"})
 * @Assert\Regex("/^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+$/", groups={"Basic2"})
 * @AppAssert\SaveDomain(groups={"Registration"})
 */
protected $myField;
```

I would like to validate fields in that order : Basic1, Basic2, Registration.

When I use GroupSequence in class Annotation :

```
/**
 * @Assert\GroupSequence({"MyEntity", "Basic1", "Basic2", "Registration"})
 */
class MyEntity
{
```

It works as expected, Basic1 => Basic2 => Registration :

But I need to use validation_groups as well... And when I specify it in the Type class, GroupSequence is not working anymore.

I try to use GroupSequence directly in validation_groups but it seems not working like it's said here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10287

```
$form = $this->createForm(new BlogType(), new Blog(), [
    'validation_groups' => new GroupSequence(['Basic', 'Strict']),
]);
```

But I'm putting it into the Type class into configureOptions :

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\MyEntyty',
        'validation_groups' => new GroupSequence(['Basic1', 'Basic2', 'Registration']),
    ]);
}
```

Someone know how can I use GroupSequence and validation_groups at the same time ?

The only solution I found for now is to create a custom validator specificly for this field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was bugged.

See corresponding ticket on repo : 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20929

This solution should work after correction merge.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\MyEntyty',
        'validation_groups' => new GroupSequence(['Basic1', 'Basic2', 'Registration']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: There still appears be an open bug related to GroupSequence: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9939

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify the groupsequence in the entity field as follow:

```
/**
 * @Assert\GroupSequence({"Basic1", "Basic2", "Registration"})
 */
class MyEntity
{

/**
 * @Assert\Regex("/^[a-z0-9-]+$/", groups={"Basic1"})
 * @Assert\Regex("/^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+$/", groups={"Basic2"})
 * @AppAssert\SaveDomain(groups={"Registration"})
 */
protected $myField;
```

Hope this help

Comment: I'm already doing that, but when I add validation_groups in the class Type, it's not working anymore.